# Which function sends ARP packet to ARPD daemon in Linux kernel?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, linux-kernel, arp

AFAIK, `arpd` is used to offload certain jobs and memory footprint from kernel. The `arpd` process can get packets from two sockets:

1. notification messages from kernel via NETLINK
2. regular ARP packets such as `ARP_REPLY` from the host's neighbors, via a `PF_PACKET` `socket`.

My question is, how are ARP packets delivered to a userspace socket? When network stack receives an ARP packet, it passes it to [`arp_rcv()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5/source/net/ipv4/arp.c#L936) and [`arp_process()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5/source/net/ipv4/arp.c#L675) kernel functions, but I wasn't able to locate any code that sends packet to the [`PF_PACKET` `socket`](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/master/misc/arpd.c#L759) that `arpd` registered. I am sure I missed something here..